# Windows 7 in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit. In the same system I had also installed VirtualBox for Windows 7. It was alright since last several months. Today there was an OS update through Software Updater. During installation it was observed that VirtualBox update couldn't be installed. However, after reboot, when I went for launch of VirtualBox, Windows couldn't start, rather total system was hanged. Need solutions to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be solved. For others, I mention below the details how it is settled. I did it with the help of Lonnie Best (lonniebest@startport.com).

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add 

sudo apt remove virtualbox

sudo apt update

sudo apt install virtualbox-5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your update installed the new Meltdown workaround Kernel 4.13 for Ubuntu 16.04 HWE, the current Virtualbox from Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't run anymore but freezes the entire system. Please see this bug report here, including a workaround PPA :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1736116